# Console is displaying this error Curl error 51: Cert verify failed: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_EXPIRED

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont know how this has happened but I was just drawing a map using Tilemaps on Unity2D and all of a sudden this error displays itself on the console: Curl error 51: **Cert verify failed: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_EXPIRED.**

I'm not sure why this is happening but it keeps coming up every few seconds and it's getting annoying. I've reinstalled Unity Hub to see if it would quickly fix it but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this error keeps popping up because Unity Servers are down.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/curl-error-51-cert-verify-failed-unitytls_x509verify_flag_expired.786755/page-2

From the link:

“Unity's website is down, it's very likely just the editor trying to grab some info online that it's not reaching it properly.”

Comment: using external links alone is not good because it can go dead. You should also paste the important part here