# Curl error 51: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_NOT_TRUSTED Error, Unity Get request issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get-request

I'm trying to send a get request to a link with parameters in it. After that, I just want to print the html. But, everytime I run the code, I get a: "Curl error 51: Cert verify failed: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_NOT_TRUSTED."

Here's my code:

```
public string theLink = https://unsmbp.uns.nova.edu/SeniorApps/facelets/registration/loginCenter.xhtml?form:userId=da1245&form:userPassword=uNs15129&AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&form=form&javax.faces.ViewState=j_id1&form:signIn=form:signIn&AJAX:EVENTS_COUNT=1;

Void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(CheckLink());
}

IEnumerator CheckLink()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(theLink);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }            
}
```

I have no clue whats wrong with it, as if you go to the page you can see it has html in it. I'd appreciate some help, as I'm pretty new to networking.

Comment: You aren’t handling the certificate

Comment: @BugFinder so how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Google. Im on a phone and not writing out chunks of code. But there are plenty of examples of handling certificates out there.

Comment: There is actually a similar thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681392/console-is-displaying-this-error-curl-error-51-cert-verify-failed-unitytls-x50